# Accessing current transaction ID within a smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, block-explorer

Is it possible to access the current transaction ID from within a smart contract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issue on github: [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5569) which refers to [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4980). According to these two links, you cannot access directly the transaction id, but the id is a calculated value, so you can compute it in your smart contract. From the second link, you can get this code:

```
void test_transaction::test_read_transaction() {
   using namespace eosio;
   checksum256 h;
   auto size = transaction_size();
   char buf[size];
   uint32_t read = read_transaction( buf, size );
   eosio_assert( size == read, "read_transaction failed");
   sha256(buf, read, &h);
   printhex( &h, sizeof(h) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an updated example using EOSIO CDT 1.6 code syntax

```
checksum256 get_trx_id() {
    size_t size = transaction_size();
    char buf[size];
    size_t read = read_transaction( buf, size );
    check( size == read, "read_transaction failed");
    return sha256( buf, read );
}
```

Afterwards you can include `get_trx_id` method into other parts of your smart contract.

```
table.emplace( payer, [&]( auto & row ) {
    row.trxid   = get_trx_id();
});
```

Comment: is this still working? I get `undeclared identifier` for transaction_size(), read_transaction(), and sha256().

Comment: Edit: you must include `eosiolib/crypto.h` and `eosiolib/transaction.h`. However, the sha256 function header is different from the way it is used here.